# How to change the selectIndex of a selectBox in an HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, htmlcollection

I'm trying to reset the values of all the selectBoxes on my page. The event in question is happening in an onClick so everything is loaded in the DOM.

I have obtained an HTMLCollection of selectBoxes via `var selectBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("selectBox");` I would like to now change the selectIndex of each of those selectBoxes to 0.

However, every time I try to access a property of a specific object from the HTMLCollection, I end up with an undefined value.

selectBoxes.item(0).selectedIndex = undefined
selectBoxes[0].selectedIndex = undefined

```
var selectBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("filterBox");
  console.log(selectBoxes); //a nice JavaScriptObject
  for(i = 0; i < selectBoxes.length; i++){
      selectBoxes.item(i).selectedIndex = 0;
  }
```

This is a very interesting article on HTMLCollections: https://hackernoon.com/htmlcollection-nodelist-and-array-of-objects-da42737181f9 which seems to be explaining part of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accessing the selectedIndex property incorrectly. It's not a direct property of the selectBox itself but rather it seems to be inside the children of the selectBox.

```
  var selectBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("filterBox");
  for(i = 0; i < selectBoxes.length; i++){
      selectBoxes.item(i).children[0].selectedIndex = 0;
  }
```